# ExactTarget Fuel API

Tags: api, marketing-cloud, fuel

When I run the code below, which is provided in the .NET Fuel SDK example code, I get a post status of false and code of 200.  The message is blank.  Why is this not working???

```
ET_Client myclient = new ET_Client();
string SubscriberTestEmail = "abc@def.com";

Console.WriteLine("\n Create Subscriber");
ET_Subscriber postSub = new ET_Subscriber();
postSub.AuthStub = myclient;
postSub.EmailAddress = SubscriberTestEmail;
FuelSDK.ET_ProfileAttribute[] etAttrs = new ET_ProfileAttribute[1];
etAttrs[0] = new ET_ProfileAttribute() { Name = "First Name", Value = "ExactTarget Example" };

PostReturn postResponse = postSub.Post();
Console.WriteLine("Post Status: " + postResponse.Status.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Message: " + postResponse.Message.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Code: " + postResponse.Code.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Results Length: " + postResponse.Results.Length);

if (postResponse.Results.Length > 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("--NewID: " + postResponse.Results[0].NewID.ToString());
  foreach (ET_ProfileAttribute attr in ((ET_Subscriber)postResponse.Results[0].Object).Attributes)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Name: " + attr.Name + ", Value: " + attr.Value);
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume you have created an app, set up your clientID/clientSecret appropriately, and have permissions to create subscribers?

Comment: After the line that currently reads:                 Console.WriteLine("--NewID: " + postResponse.Results[0].NewID.ToString());

add: Console.WriteLine("--NewID: " + postResponse.Results[0].StatusMessage); then let us know the output.